# UICTContentSizeCategory in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was setting row heights in a table view based on accessibility text options and my first dictionary was giving me errors because the values returned from

```
let userSize = UIApplication.sharedApplication().preferredContentSizeCategory
```

were not matching with my dictionary. I ended up having to replace all the UIContentSizeCategory keys with the following strings:

```
 let cellHeightDictionary: Dictionary = [
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryXS": 44,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryS": 44,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryM": 44,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryL": 44,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryXL": 55,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryXXL": 65,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryXXXL": 65,

                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityM": 65,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityL": 65,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityXL": 65,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityXXL": 65,
                                             "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityXXXL": 75]
```

But I can't find any information about the "UICTContentSizeCategory" in the documentation. 
Are these just new to iOS? Is there an exhaustive list of these somewhere so I don't need to print out the values returned to find out what they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dictionary you should use the constants, and not the content (i.e. the actual string value) of these constants.

E.g. use this:

```
let cellHeightDictionary = [
    UIContentSizeCategoryExtraSmall : 44,
    UIContentSizeCategorySmall : 44
]
```

instead of:

```
let cellHeightDictionary = [
    "UICTContentSizeCategoryXS": 44,
    "UICTContentSizeCategoryS": 44
]
```

here are the constants that are currently defined:

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryExtraSmall: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategorySmall: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryMedium: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryLarge: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraLarge: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge: NSString!

// Accessibility sizes
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityMedium: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityLarge: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraLarge: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraLarge: NSString!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
let UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: NSString!
```